# 125 000 000 arrayLists?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I did some numbers and ended up finding that on my application, if the user uses the max setting possible, I will need to create like 125 000 000 arrayLists.

It is a tile-based map editor. Nice. I use a 2d array map for storing my map's data.
The max map's dimension allowed will need 100 000 000+ arrayLists.

Is this okay? Do you have a better idea? I know I could use List(Of T), but I do have reasons to use arrayList in this.. special scenario of mine.

Maybe I should reduce the max settings allowed huh...

Comment: If you've got a terabyte of RAM, you might be ok.

Comment: To give you a better idea about the data structure, we will need more information about the data stored.... Your description doesn't explain why there's a 125000000 limit, or what are the 2d arrays for, or what the arraylists are for.

Comment: Omega: has anyone introduced you to the `List(Of T)` class? ;)

Comment: @Yochai: Well, my map is represented by a 2d array: One arrayList for the X coordinates, one arrayList inside each X one represents the Y coordinates. And finally, another ArrayList inside each X,Y stores three elements: One string, one integer, and another integer. They are data needed for drawing my tile later, when I need to.

@Adam: .... >___>.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never show all tiles in one go - limit the number of tiles in memory to those that *can* be displayed in one go.

If you are allowing zooming, consider a max zoom level that will still let the editor to function well but not require an insane amount of memory to work.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the "limit the number of tiles in memory" part? I must also point out: in my app, a "tile" is essentially an ArrayList of three elements. The three elements are data to draw the tile image later.

Comment: @Omega - How small must a tile be in order to be manipulated? Figure out the size (heigh & width), then knowing the screen resolution (or window/picturebox size) you can figure out how many such tiles can fit in the display. Only load the relevant ones.

Comment: I see, by "load" you mean "paint it", right? So it is ok to have 125M arrayLists?

Comment: @Omega - No, not really. I mean load into memory. You can have 125M _items_, but can only have a smaller number of them in memory any one time. You can save them into a file, database or something else, but you _can't_ have them all in memory - it's too much.